TextInput error after changing the expo workflow from managed to bare
I changed my app from managed to bare and added native iOS and Android folders, on Android I can log in, but on iOS when trying to log in I get this error

[RTIInputSystemClient remoteTextInputSessionWithID:performInputOperation:] perform input operation requires a valid sessionID. inputModality = Keyboard, inputOperation = , customInfoType = UIEmojiSearchOperations

what could it be? The problems are with something native to iOS
